# Is there a way to group columns in MUI-dataTable?

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am using MUIDataTable in my React project. I just want to group columns by adding borders to the table. Please find the code below which I am using.

```
const columns = [
 {
  name: "name",
  label: "Name",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: true,
   [customBodyRender: (value) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ borderRight: "solid 2px" }} >
              {value}
            </div>
          )
        }][1]
  }
 },
 {
  name: "company",
  label: "Company",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
  }
 },
 {
  name: "city",
  label: "City",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
   customBodyRender: (value) => {
          return (
            <div style={{ borderRight: "solid 2px" }} >
              {value}
            </div>
          )
        }
  }
 },
 {
  name: "state",
  label: "State",
  options: {
   filter: true,
   sort: false,
  }
 },
];

const data = [
 { name: "Joe James", company: "Test Corp", city: "Yonkers", state: "NY" },
 { name: "John Walsh", company: "Test Corp", city: "Hartford", state: "CT" },
 { name: "Bob Herm", company: "Test Corp", city: "Tampa", state: "FL" },
 { name: "James Houston", company: "Test Corp", city: "Dallas", state: "TX" },
 { name: "", company: "", city: "Tampa", state: "" },
    { name: "", company: "", city: "", state: "" },
    { name: "", company: "", city: "Hartford", state: "" },
    { name: "", company: "", city: "", state: "" },
    { name: "", company: "", city: "", state: "" },
    { name: "", company: "", city: "", state: "" },
];
 
const options = {
  filterType: 'checkbox',
};
 
<MUIDataTable
  title={"Employee List"}
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  options={options}
/>
```

This is not working as expected. Either the border height is not proper or in case of no data in the table row, there is no border at all.
I also want the borders to appear on the table headers.

I have attached the snapshot of the output for reference.
[OutputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZyfC.png)

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

there is a PR but it's in beta only https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/pull/1441, not yet merged into the master branch